# Errors in installing FFTW locally

Tags: linux, libraries

I'm trying to install [fftw-3.3.7 library](http://www.fftw.org/) in a Linux cluster locally. After extracting, I tried,

```
./configure
make
make install
```

This throws me a bunch of errors and "permission denied" statements. A part of the text in the terminal after the command `make install` is given here:

```
/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/include'
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 fftw3.h fftw3.f fftw3l.f03 fftw3q.f03 '/usr/local/include'
/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file `/usr/local/include/fftw3.h': Permission denied
/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file `/usr/local/include/fftw3.f': Permission denied
/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file `/usr/local/include/fftw3l.f03': Permission denied
/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file `/usr/local/include/fftw3q.f03': Permission denied
make[3]: *** [install-includeHEADERS] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/NewUser/fftw-3.3.7/api'
make[2]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/NewUser/fftw-3.3.7/api'
make[1]: *** [install] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/NewUser/fftw-3.3.7/api'
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

I am not familiar with Linux much. Could you please explain why these errors and permission denied statements occur? How can I install this fftw-3.3.7 locally in a cluster in my home folder?

Comment: You must be root ( `$ su` ) to  do 'make install' . Or use `$ sudo make install`

Comment: @KnudLarsen I would like to install the library without "sudo" (i.e., locally)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing fftw3 locally, example ...

```
$ ./configure --prefix=/home/NewUser/fftw3
$ make
$ make install
```

Which will install to `home/NewUser/fftw3/{ include/, lib/ }`

Comment: Could you please tell me where to find following files: fftw3d.o fft3dlib.o . I couldn't find these files in */fftw/lib and *fftw/include directories. I would like to link these libraries to compile VASP5.2 code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be `root` to write to `/usr`. If you want to install a program to a non-standard location you need to use `--prefix`:

```
./configure --prefix=/tmp/local-install
make
make install
```

The above will install your program to `/tmp/local-install` directory.